# Though the elements in the old and new list share the same reference, changes to an item in new list does not reflect in old list

Tags: python

I created a list l1 and used shallow copy to create another list l2. From the code below , I see the item in the list (for eg : l1[0] and l2[0]) share the same memory address.

When I try to modify an item l2[0]. I do not see the change in l1[0]
I was expecting the same change to reflect in l1[0] as well since they share the same location in memory.

```
Code:

import copy
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = copy.copy(l1)
print(id(l1[0]))
print(id(l2[0]))
l2[0] = 100
print("ll - ",l1)
print("l2 - ",l2)

Output:

140733778727720
140733778727720
ll -  [1, 2, 3]
l2 -  [100, 2, 3]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXq9b.jpg

Comment: Of course not, *it is a different list*. The fact that the list is referring to the same objects as another list doesn't mean that if you make that list refer to another object at some index that the other list will. **that is why it is a copy**